# odd javascript/php variable type

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

Hey guys sorry for your time but I have came across to an odd situation. I have a database where I store coordinates (php & mysql) with names. When someone searches for something a php script runs and save the query in 3 different variables which it should be of an array type. Then I use JavaScript to convert these php arrays to JavaScript ones. The coordinates are ok, but the names are of type string when I try split() function it gives error because it is an array (as I understand after searching). The other odd is when I console.log the typeof name it says string but when I look in sources it is displayed like an array.

```
var lon = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $lon) . '"]' ?>;
var lat = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $lat) . '"]' ?>;
var name = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $name) . '"]' ?>;
```

the output in sources tab (chrome)

```
 var lon = ["39.070200", "39.072365", "39.064469"];
 var lat = ["21.018064", "21.017744", "21.000059"];
 var name = ["Saint Dimitrios", "Saint Charalampos", "Saint Kosmas"];
```

and then for the console

```
console.log(lon);
console.log(typeof lon);
console.log( typeof name);
```

the actual output in console

```
["21.018064", "21.017744", "21.000059"] //which when I click it identifies it as an array
object
string
```

the declaration in php script

```
$lon = [];
$lat = [];
$name = [];
```

and the fetching

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $name[] = $row['name'];
        $lon[] = $row['lon'];
        $lat[] = $row['lat'];
}
```

Comment: As the post @Xufox refers to, name is a reserved keyword in the window scope and hence it's typeof will return String. The may confusion occur because javascript data types are dynamic

Comment: @MathiasW `name` is _not_ a reserved keyword. It’s a property that has a getter–setter-like behavior. When set, it is cast to string. This doesn’t really relate to dynamic typing. `window.name` just has a special purpose and needs to remain a string.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Xufox, my bad!

Comment: Yew using the variable name doesn't work! when I changed it as @Xufox suggested it works fine. Sorry for your time and thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript arrays are objects with keys as numbers.

Try to create in console `arr = new Array` and then call `typeof(arr)` to see your newly created array in vanilla JavaScript environement is an object too.

Beware! When creating new array in JavaScript `length` property is automatically added to it. So if you try to log every element in array with `foreach` loop you'll get one more property that is reserved for length of your array.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.forEach( function(key,i,arr) {
  console.log(key)
})

//output
   1
   2
   3
   undefined
```

Trying to `split()` an array is not an option as this function takes string value and breaks it down to array with defined divider ex.

```
'1,2,3'.split(',')
//result
["1", "2", "3"]
```

P.S. Functions in JS are objects too. So basically you can make something like this:

```
function myFunc() {
 alert('Hello World');
};

myFunc.myProperty = '123';
```

And now you can call your function as usual with `myFunc()` and also get it's property with `console.log(myFunc.myProperty)`